# My cat is refusing to eat for 4 days?

Tags: cats, diet, weight

My cat have not eaten anything for 5 days that he became so skinny, so I went to the vet and he got his temperature normal also looked at the cat ear wax through a microscope and it seemed normal, so he tried to get a blood sample but he couldn't get it right because the sample was very small and clotted also. so he wrote him some vitamins that help to increase appetite but still he refuses to eat. the cat is 11(eleven) years old and he is a male. I'm asking to see if anyone had this problem, I'm in Egypt now and the vets here are not really qualified for serious or hard cases and I disparately need some help or at least any advice. also please note that i cant see any worms in his feces and that he through out his life he was very picky about his food and sometimes he refuses to eat but return back to normal within few days but this time it has been far longer.

Comment: Maybe you can see/call another vet for advice? This site is not guessing and it is impossible to diagnose from far away. But if you wait for general advice about getting back appetite, then we can help.

Comment: And note that extended fasting can be very dangerous for cats. You need to resolve this as fast as possible, even if it means force feeding.

Comment: Does he drink? Water? Can you coax him to drink e.g. unsalted broth (no  salt or veggies, just meat & bones cooked in water)?

Comment: I struggle a bit with a clear question (as @Allerleirauh also implies). A “yes” answer to “has anyone experienced this” probably won’t help you much, do you perhaps mean “how can I get him to eat” or “is it a problem apart from him being skinny”. We can’t diagnose over the Internet so for that you’ll have to find another vet locally, sorry.

Comment: @Stephie I'm really sorry but as i said I'm in Egypt now and the vets here are totally unqualified they cant even take a blood sample from the cat so i'm trying to get any advice. about forced feeding i'm afraid to get him aspiration pneumonia so do you have any advice to try to decrease this risk.